# what rewriting rule missing in HTTP_HOST on IIS7 for this app?

Tags: iis, iis-7

I followed this tutorial
http://blog.endjin.com/2010/11/a-step-by-step-guide-to-hosting-youtrack-in-iis-7/

It created this rule

> Click the “Add Condition” button. You will be shown the following
>   dialog. Enter “{HTTP_HOST}” in the “Condition input” field and your
>   custom subdomain (ours is bugs.endjin.com) in the “Pattern” field.
>   Then click “Ok”

It works for url like
http://subdomain.domain.com/issue

but not for
http://subdomain.domain.com/what/users+groups
that last kind gives 404 error

so do you know what would be missing ?

It seems IIS support is very lacking compared to Apache : I never get real response quickly when it's about IIS hope better for this time :)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by IIS 7 treating ‘+’ as dangerous character by default, and refusing all such requests.

To change this behavior:

- open IIS Manager,
- click on server,
- open IIS -> Request Filtering,
- click Rules tab -> Edit Feature Settings,
- check the “Allow double escaping” checkbox.

Notes:

- this will disable the filtering for whole server i.e. also for the other apps it may host. I haven’t yet found a way to set this setting on webfarm level. Of course even if filtering is disabled on global level it can be re-enabled per each app, you’ll just have to do it manually for each app
- the option does more than just allow ‘+’ in urls, so be sure to read about it in more details especially in case of internet-facing server

From : http://blog.endjin.com/2010/11/a-step-by-step-guide-to-hosting-youtrack-in-iis-7/

Comment: Just noticed your domain in the original question, I've given you a link from your own blog! Nevermind...